What cause the banding when shooting under fluorescent lamps?
I observe banding has appeared when shooting under fluorescent lighting. What may cause that? I think because of flickering we observe banding. Am I right? Or is there any other reason for that?

Neither of the "duplicates" address fluorescent lights specifically. One is about neon, the other about LEDs. Perhaps a more general question, which addresses flicker in general and in which the accepted answer addresses multiple flickering light sources, including fluorescent lighting, would be a closer duplicate? What causes these inconsistent dark bands in some of my photos from an indoor event?
